# How to populate TableView in JavaFX using alias

Tags: sqlite, javafx

While using swing everything works just fine.

```
String sql= "SELECT idrepair as '№',"
        + "case when repairStatus in (0) then 'Not Done' "
        + "when repairStatus in (1) then 'Closed' "
        + "when repairStatus in (2) then 'Open' "
        + "else 'Unknown' end as  'Status'"
        + "FROM repairjournal";
```

I just want new UI using JavaFX, so here is my code, i would say my efforts:

```
    private void loadTableViewRepList(ObservableList oblist, Connection conn, TableView table) {
            oblist.clear();
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM repairjournal";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    oblist.add(new ModelTableRepairList(
                           rs.getString("idrepair"),
                           rs.getString("case when repairStatus in (0) then 'Not Done' "
               + "when repairStatus in (1) then 'Closed' "
               + "when repairStatus in (2) then 'Open' "
               + "else 'Unknown' end ")
                                       ));
                }
                table.setItems(oblist);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(RepairListController
.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

or

```
    private void loadTableViewRepList(ObservableList oblist, Connection conn, TableView table) {
                oblist.clear();
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT idrepair, 
case when repairStatus in (0) then 
'Not Done.' when repairStatus in (1) then
 'Closed' when repairStatus in (2) then 'Open' 
                    else 'Unknown' end as 'Status' FROM repairjournal";
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        oblist.add(new ModelTableRepairList(
                               rs.getString("idrepair"),
                               rs.getString("repairStatus")
                                           ));
                    }
                    table.setItems(oblist);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(RepairListController
    .class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
```

> Main error is no such column: 'repairStatus'

Any ideas how to fix this? Yes i can rename data, but i have more tables with such data in DB.

Comment: `getString("")` returns info from a column with the `String` name. Do you have a column named `"case when repairStatus in (0) then 'Not Done' "
               + "when repairStatus in (1) then 'Closed' "
               + "when repairStatus in (2) then 'Open' "
               + "else 'Unknown' end "`?

Comment: Did you try `rs.getString(0),
                               rs.getString(1)`?

Comment: I would suggest you just return repairStatus (if it's spelled correctly) and then do the case logic in code. You may need to take a look how your database table columns.

Comment: 1."Do you have a column named..." - no
2."Did you try rs.getString(0)" - yes. It returns numbers. Same as Select * form tablename. I need to change it to String. Status '1' means that it is done, 0 - no. For users.

Comment: 3. "and then do the case logic in code." - how to do that? 
In swing i use if-else case for filling labels with correct String instead of numbers. But how to populate Table - i have no idea, as i said in swing - was easy.
idrepair and repairStatus - column names

Comment: Something like: `String outputString = ""; String tempRepairStatus = rs.getString("repairStatus); if(tempReparStatus.equals("0");{//ouptString = "Not Done"}else if(...){...}else if(...){...}  oblist.add(new ModelTableRepairList(
                               rs.getString("idrepair"),
                               outputString
                                           ));`

Comment: I just noticed you said it returns numbers. You should use `int tempRepairStatus = rs.getInt(1); if(tempRepairStatus == 0){outString = "Not Done}...

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: no such column: '1' - this is 1st value from row. So i can assume, that data need to be  aliased after it gets, not before.